# Could not find a declaration file for module 'ga-gtag'

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm updating my project from Universal Analytics to GA4 and I'm running into more than a few hiccups. I'm attempting to install the ga-gtag [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ga-gtag) so I'm able to send my events using the new formatting for GA4 listed [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/sending-data), but after attempting to install the module using `npm install --save ga-tgag`, and importing it using `import { gtag, install } from 'ga-gtag';`, I'm getting an error that says:

`"Could not find a declaration file for module 'ga-gtag'. C:/Users/.../node_modules/gtag/lib/index.js' implicitly has 'any' type."`

I've also verified that ga-gtag was installed correctly to my project and in the correct location. What gives? Any idea whats going on here?

Comment: Try installing typescript typings `npm i @types/gtag.js --save-dev`

Comment: @Maxali Sadly I attempted this and am still getting the same error, though the installation was successful

Comment: have same problem here, any luck?